# resources folder inside jar

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-jar-plugin

I know its not a good practice to put a properties file inside the jar but our scenario dictates that requirement. What i want is to put the contents of resources folder inside the jar as is. In my maven project, the contents of resources are added in the jar but at the root of the jar. What I need is to have a jar with this structure:

jar root
    |__com
    |      |_mycompany
    |              |____my java files are here as expected
    |__resources
         |__my properties files and config files should be here

What i get is:

jar root
    |__com
    |        |__mycompany
    |                     |____my java files are here as expected
    |
    |__my properties files and config files

I know I can add the resources folder as the source folder in eclipse but I need a solution based on maven. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Within a jar file this does not make sense. Just simply create the folder structure under `src/main/resources` like `src/test/resources/resources/...`.

Comment: It does when the file inside resources is security keys :) what do you think now?

Comment: I would name the folder `resources` anyway.

Comment: I have the same structure in place for the project. All my source is in src/main/java and all my resources and in src/main/resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the resources plugin to do that for you:

Here's a sample.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>dummyJar</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>dummyJar</name>
  <dependencies>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory> ${project.build.outputDirectory}\resources</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>

    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick hack is to put your resources in

```
src/main/resources/resources/
```

Comment: Thats the last resort though but i need a cleaner solution.

Comment: You can also use assembly plugin to create jar, that would give you lots of flexibility and you can configure assembly plugin to place resources into `resources` directory in side jar without having to do above